# Setting image property of UIImageView causes major lag

Tags: performance, asynchronous, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics

Let me tell you about the problem I am having and how I tried to solve it. I have a UIScrollView which loads subviews as one scrolls from left to right. Each subview has 10-20 images around 400x200 each. When I scroll from view to view, I experience quite a bit of lag.

After investigating, I discovered that after unloading all the views and trying it again, the lag was gone. I figured that the synchronous caching of the images was the cause of the lag. So I created a subclass of UIImageView which loaded the images asynchronously. The loading code looks like the following (`self.dispatchQueue` returns a serial dispatch queue).

```
- (void)loadImageNamed:(NSString *)name {
    dispatch_async(self.dispatchQueue, ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.image = image;
        });
    });
}
```

However, after changing all of my UIImageViews to this subclass, I still experienced lag (I'm not sure if it was lessened or not). I boiled down the cause of the problem to `self.image = image;`. Why is this causing so much lag (but only on the first load)?

Please help me. =(

Answer (score 57, accepted):

EDIT 3: iOS 15 now offers [`UIImage.prepareForDisplay(completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3750844-preparefordisplay).

```swift
imageView.image = await image.byPreparingForDisplay()
```

or

```swift
image.prepareForDisplay { decodedImage in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        imageView.image = decodedImage
    }
}
```

---

EDIT 2: Here is a Swift version that contains a few improvements. (Untested.)
https://gist.github.com/fumoboy007/d869e66ad0466a9c246d

---

EDIT: Actually, I believe all that is necessary is the following. (Untested.)

```objectivec
- (void)loadImageNamed:(NSString *)name {
    dispatch_async(self.dispatchQueue, ^{
        // Determine path to image depending on scale of device's screen,
        // fallback to 1x if 2x is not available
        NSString *pathTo1xImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"png"];
        NSString *pathTo2xImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[name stringByAppendingString:@"@2x"] ofType:@"png"];

        NSString *pathToImage = ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 1 || !pathTo2xImage) ? pathTo1xImage : pathTo2xImage;


        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];

        // Decompress image
        if (image) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);

            [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }


        // Configure the UI with pre-decompressed UIImage
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.image = image;
        });
    });
}
```

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER: It turns out that it wasn't `self.image = image;` directly. The UIImage image loading methods don't decompress and process the image data right away; they do it when the view refreshes its display. So the solution was to go a level lower to Core Graphics and decompress and process the image data myself. The new code looks like the following.

```objectivec
- (void)loadImageNamed:(NSString *)name {
    dispatch_async(self.dispatchQueue, ^{
        // Determine path to image depending on scale of device's screen,
        // fallback to 1x if 2x is not available
        NSString *pathTo1xImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"png"];
        NSString *pathTo2xImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[name stringByAppendingString:@"@2x"] ofType:@"png"];
        
        NSString *pathToImage = ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 1 || !pathTo2xImage) ? pathTo1xImage : pathTo2xImage;
        
        
        UIImage *uiImage = nil;
        
        if (pathToImage) {
            // Load the image
            CGDataProviderRef imageDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([pathToImage fileSystemRepresentation]);
            CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imageDataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
            
            
            // Create a bitmap context from the image's specifications
            // (Note: We need to specify kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little
            // because PNGs are optimized by Xcode this way.)
            CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image), CGImageGetWidth(image) * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
            
            
            // Draw the image into the bitmap context
            CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
            
            //  Extract the decompressed image
            CGImageRef decompressedImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
            
            
            // Create a UIImage
            uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:decompressedImage];
            
            
            // Release everything
            CGImageRelease(decompressedImage);
            CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
            CGImageRelease(image);
            CGDataProviderRelease(imageDataProvider);
        }
        
        
        // Configure the UI with pre-decompressed UIImage
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.image = uiImage;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Oops…sorry about that little bug.

Comment: This was very helpful. For people who come to this question just needing to make a UIImage from a UIView, I found this solution after piecing through many answers:

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(processing.bounds.size);

`        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

 `       [processing.layer renderInContext:ctx];

 `       UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`

Comment: amazing answer, still very helpful in 2015 :)

Comment: You have to dispatch on main thread after prepareForDisplay

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem could be Images themselves. For example - I got in one of my projects 10 images 640x600 layered with alpha transparency on each other. When I try to push or pop viewcontroller from this viewcontroller.. it lags a lot.

when I leave only few images or use quite smaller images - no lag.

P.S. tested on sdk 4.2 ios5  iphone 4.

Comment: But mine only lags on the first load!