# Source of lag when adding/removing UIViews to UIScrollview?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, lag, addsubview

***Problem:***

Adding/removing `subviews` to/from a `UIScrollView` causes noticeable lag.

***Details:***

I have a `UIScrollView` (with paging `enabled`) that will contain a couple dozen 'pages'.  The content size of this `UIScrollview` is the number of pages * the width of the `UIScrollView`.

Each of these pages is a `subview` that I build from some file system access. My `UIScrollView` keeps three pages around as `subviews`: the current page, and its left/right neighbours. Loading/eviction of the neighbouring `subviews` takes place when the current page is half offscreen, which is when the disk access and manipulation of view hierarchy occurs.

When I first encountered this my immediate thought was that the disk access/building the `subview` is the source of the lag. I've since moved to this an `NSTimer`, and am still experiencing the same lag.

I'm starting to suspect that the lag is caused by `addSubview` (adding `subview` to `UIScrollView`) and `removeFromSuperview` (removing `subviews` from `UIScrollView`).

`Subviews` are added directly to `UIScrollView`.  I don't have a 'content view' inside the `UIScrollView` that I add them to.

***Question:***

Is this a common problem/bottleneck?  Is there a better pattern for loading of these pages?

Comment: if the subViews you are adding contain large resource files (images) then you may notice lag as the images are loaded into memory depending on the size of the images.

Comment: Hmm.  The subviews we're adding are a subclass of UIScrollView, and their content is an image that's 2048x2048, and usually weighs in about 2MB.

Comment: try using small image files or no images and see if the lag is still there... if not, then you probably need to look into lazy loading the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being setting the image property of the subviews.  UIImage does not perform its processing right away, only in preparation for appearing on screen -- this is what was causing the lag.

The question lead me down the right track:

[Setting image property of UIImageView causes major lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790183/setting-image-property-of-uiimageview-causes-major-lag)

Their solution was to decompress/process the image ourselves using Core Graphics, and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` typically runs on the main thread. If you're doing synchronous disk access on the main thread, then that's going to cause stuttering. How are you reading your files?

Comment: They're done with one of our libraries, but ultimately they'll be read with UIImage imageNamed:.

Comment: You need to do this on a background thread if these files are large.