# Creating an NSCache for the first time with CloudKit Records - close?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, caching, cloudkit

I have a project I'm close to completing. My last problem arises when I've downloaded CloudKit records to an array to be displayed in a tableview. Here is my code for the query portion of the controller.

```
           for result in results!
            {
                let tablerestaurant = Restaurant()
                if let name = result.value(forKey: "Name") as! String? {
                    tablerestaurant.name = name
                }
                // Do same for image
                if let imageAsset = result.object(forKey: "Picture") as! CKAsset? {   
                    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageAsset.fileURL) {
                        tablerestaurant.image =  UIImage(data: data)
                    }
                }
                self.tablerestaurantarray.append(tablerestaurant) // tablerestaurant is an array holding string and image instances of class Restaurant
                self.restaurantArray.append(result) // restaurantArray holds CKRecords to be segued to the next controller 
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation( { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.activity.isHidden = true
            })}
```

and here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath Tablecell function, with the cache portion commented along with the global arrays here

```
 var tablerestaurantarray: [Restaurant] = []
 let cache = NSCache<NSString, Restaurant>()
```

-

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt     indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:     "restaurantcell") as? RestaurantTableCell


    /////////this is the cache portion//////////////
    var oneRestaurant: Restaurant = tablerestaurantarray[indexPath.row]

    if let cachedVersion = cache.Restaurant(forKey: "image")
        {
            oneRestaurant = cachedVersion
    }
    else
    {
        oneRestaurant = Restaurant()
        cache.setObject(oneRestaurant, forKey: "image")
    }
    //////////////////////////


    let restaurant: Restaurant = tablerestaurantarray[indexPath.row]
    cell?.name?.text = oneRestaurant.name

   // cell?.picture?.image = oneRestaurant.image
    return cell!
```

I've attempted to copy this simply cache procedure from here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-cache-data-using-nscache and transcribe it towards my own use. However, the debugger states that

```
NSCache<NSString, Restaurant> has no member Restaurant
```

which it does. So I'm lost as to my problem. Would you have an idea?

Update 2

```
 var tablerestaurantarray: [Restaurant] = []
 let cache = NSCache<NSString , Restaurant>()


var oneRestaurant: Restaurant = tablerestaurantarray[indexPath.row]


    if let cachedVersion = cache.object(forKey: "image") { } //error is called here
    {
        oneRestaurant = cachedVersion
    }
    else
    {
        oneRestaurant = Restaurant()
        cache.setObject(oneRestaurant, forKey: "image")
    }
```

Comment: do you only need to cache the image? The error you're receiving is that `NSCache` doesn't recognize your custom `Restaurant` class. It should however recognize a `UIImage`. If you only need the image, try making your cache `NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()` and then to set the object, instead of using the `Restaurant` object, just use it's image `oneRestaurant.image` (assuming you named the Restaurant's image property "image")

Comment: Yes, unless caching the string would be helpful (I have my doubts thought(.

Comment: Like so? Updated answer.

Comment: that might work, although what's strange is your original idea should have worked too, just as you copied it from the tutorial. I copied your code into a new project and it worked fine making a cache with a custom Restaurant class

Comment: There's a problem with how you have it setup now though. You set the `oneRestaurant` to be equal to an entry from your array, but then you do a conditional binding check on the cache, and if it doesn't exist, you reset `oneRestaurant` to an empty `Restaurant` object, which means it won't have an image.

Comment: If I were to go back to the original post (since it seems this was closer), why am I encountering the "no member Restaurant" error?

Comment: the problem stems from when you says `cache.Restaurant`. `NSCache` doesn't have any variable named `Restaurant`. You need to say `if let cachedVersion = cache.object(forKey: "image") { } `

Comment: But now I have the "extra argument "forKey" in call" error? Im sorry for the numerous questions, the logic seems straightforward but almost backward as well.

Comment: The update has been updated.

Comment: you have one too many sets of curly brackets. I only put `{ }` to show a symbol for a completed function. In fact you can remove both of those after the `cache.object(forKey: "image")` because you already have a set after

Comment: Errors are gone, but with "cell?.picture.image = oneRestaurant.image", my images are no appearing.

Comment: Read my comment eight comments up ^

Comment: After deciphering what I believe you were hinting at, I deleted " oneRestaurant = Restaurant()". My image(s) shows up, but it is the same one image for all table cells, despite the purpose of the function - cellForRowAt...

Comment: You probably want a cache for each Restaurant

Comment: correct. But shouldn't that be taken care of naturally by the function? I was under the impression the cell function was like a for loop, running for each new cell?

Comment: You are right: An NSCache can store multiple objects. You use keys to address them. You only ever use one key ("image"), therefore you always retrieve the same object from the cache. Writing an object to the cache using the same key overwrites the existing object. Use different keys for different objects.

Comment: Do you understand what @nils said? I think he explained it perfectly. I'm sorry I haven't been able to be of more help, I've been extremely busy the past couple days.

Comment: To you both, I am incredibly thankful for the responses! The cache is up and running! Images load fine but it seems that 3 or 4 labels actually cause some choppiness, which is odd.